# i cant call the method

Tags: java, netbeans

I did a method, but i can't call it in main. this is my code.

the error i keep getting is that it requires an int[] and found no argument

how do i call it??

```
public class Max {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(getLargest());
    }// close main

    public static int getLargest(int t[]) {
        int maximum = t[0];   // start with the first value
        for (int i = 1; i < t.length; i++) {
            if (t[i] > maximum) {
                maximum = t[i];   // new maximum
            }//close if
        }//close for
        return maximum;
    }//end method max
}//close class
```

Comment: So, it takes an `int[]` value but you want to call it with *no value whatsoever*? Nope, that's not allowed. *Read the error message again:* "found no argument".

Comment: calling to to `getLargest()` And want it to call `getLargest(int t[])` ... you have dialed wrong number!!! :)

Comment: The error describes precisely what the problem is - you need to pass `getLargest()` an `int[]` as an argument, because that is how you defined your function.

Comment: So, you've written a method that finds the largest of an array of numbers.  Fantastic.  Now you want to test it without giving it any numbers to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public static int getLargest(int t[]) is a method (as defined by your code) that works when it receives an integer array as argument. But when you are calling the method, You haven't passed any integer array to it, so how would it work?

Try doing it this way:

```
package max;

public class Max {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[]= {50, 30, 45, 78, 96};

    System.out.println(getLargest(a));

}// close main


public static int getLargest(int t[]) {

    int maximum = t[0];   // start with the first value

    for (int i = 1; i < t.length; i++) {

        if (t[i] > maximum) {

            maximum = t[i];   // new maximum

        }//close if

    }//close for

    return maximum;
}//end method max
```

}//close class

Comment: thanks, been cramming for an exam, kinda forgot the basics.

Comment: Yeah it happens... just try to understand the concepts, don't cram!!

Answer (score 1):

Turn int t[] into int[] t for the variable that will be passed inside your getLargest() method. Otherwise it will fail to work, it's not setup correctly.
You did not pass a int[] variable when calling the method. Try this and pass the variable:

```
    int[] t = {0,1,2}
    getLargest(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have define a method which take int t[] as a argument **public static int getLargest(int t[])**. but while calling you are not passing any thing as an argument to **getLargest()**

Answer (score 0):

`getLargest(int t[])` takes an array of int. That means you cannot invoke this method without passing the correct parameter.`

An array of int can be initialised as:

`int[] arr = {0, 5, 10, 15};`

and then you need to change here:

`System.out.println(getLargest());`

as

`System.out.println(getLargest(arr));`